# Incremental Number in textbox header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I just started on SSRS. I've tried and searched but I can't. I have this report from dataset1, I need the Header to contain 3 textbox with incremental numbers, where the first must be a field of dataset1. Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a Answer that work for me for me from AniyaTangMSFT-7891, in another forum!!

I have added 3 textboxes in the header with their expressions set to:
textbox1: =First(Fields!MATCHESPRIMARY.Value, "DataSet1")+3*(Globals!PageNumber-1)
textbox2: =First(Fields!MATCHESPRIMARY.Value, "DataSet1")+3*(Globals!PageNumber-1)+1
textbox3: =First(Fields!MATCHESPRIMARY.Value, "DataSet1")+3*(Globals!PageNumber-1)+2

Thanks everyone and specially AniyaTangMSFT-7891